# Initialising a 2d array

Tags: arrays, 2d

I have done 1d arrays and there is no problem, but what am I doing wrong here with 2d array?
Cant see where I'm going wrong, it must be formatting but can't see woods for the trees!

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Test_Matrix_Declared {
  class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {

      string[, ] TestLoads = new string[16, 8];

      //Enable, RQuies,   RSample, RWriteTx,   RDepass, RDischarge, DischargeDate, Discharge Time
      {
        {
          "1", "232000", "3770", "100000000", "191", "1180", "2009-04-03", "16:32:00"
        }, {
          "1", "232000", "3770", "100000000", "191", "1180", "2009-04-03", "16:32:00"
        }, {
          "1", "232000", "3770", "100000000", "191", "1180", "2009-04-03", "16:32:00"
        }, {
          "1", "232000", "3770", "100000000", "383", "1180", "2009-04-03", "16:32:00"
        }, {
          "1", "475000", "7560", "100000000", "191", "1180", "2009-04-03", "16:32:00"
        }, {
          "1", "475000", "7560", "100000000", "191", "1180", "2009-04-03", "16:32:00"
        }, {
          "1", "232000", "3770", "100000000", "191", "1180", "2009-04-03", "16:32:00"
        }, {
          "1", "232000", "3770", "100000000", "191", "1180", "2009-04-03", "16:32:00"
        }, {
          "1", "232000", "3770", "100000000", "191", "1180", "2009-04-03", "16:32:00"
        }, {
          "1", "232000", "3770", "100000000", "191", "1180", "2009-04-03", "16:32:00"
        }, {
          "1", "232000", "3770", "100000000", "191", "1180", "2009-04-03", "16:32:00"
        }, {
          "1", "232000", "3770", "100000000", "191", "1180", "2009-04-03", "16:32:00"
        }, {
          "1", "232000", "3770", "100000000", "191", "1180", "2009-04-03", "16:32:00"
        }, {
          "1", "232000", "3770", "100000000", "191", "1180", "2009-04-03", "16:32:00"
        }, {
          "1", "232000", "3770", "100000000", "191", "1180", "2009-04-03", "16:32:00"
        }, {
          "1", "232000", "3770", "100000000", "191", "1180", "2009-04-03", "16:32:00"
        }
      };
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the semicolon from the end of

```
string[,] TestLoads = new string[16,8];
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks Rad1, im not a good starter in the morning,

Comment: @StevieB, if this solved your problem, it would be great if you could up vote it and mark it as the accepted answer.

Comment: marked as Answer, cant +vote, as not enough reputation yet,, i do hope i get a good reputation at the end! ;)